# Date range based on Column Date

Tags: sql-server, date, dateadd

I am using the latest SQL Server. I have a table with a CreatedDate column. I need to write a Query that uses dates that are plus or minus 7 from the Date in CreatedDate. I have no clue how to go about this. My thought was this:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime 
DECLARE @SevenBefore datetime
DECLARE @SevenAfter datetime
SET @Date = CreatedDate
SET @SevenBefore = DATEADD(day,-7,@Date)
SET @SevenAfter = DATEADD(day,7,@Date)
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE <table> BETWEEN @SevenBefore AND @SevenAfter
```

The issue with this is that I cannot use "CreatedDate" as a SET @DATE because SQL gives an error "Invalid column name 'CreatedDate'"

Any help would be appreciated. I cannot list a date because every date in that column could be different.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting created date?  If you use the column value in a table, why bother doing +/- 7?  Can you give some context to this?  Is it in a different table?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You query doesn't even make sense. Is it `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <table>.CreatedDate BETWEEN @SevenBefore AND @SevenAfter`... ?  Which field in `<table>` are you trying to restrict to this date range?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you need to stop thinking as a programmer would, and start thinking as a Database programmer would.

Lets work only with this central part of your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE <table> BETWEEN @SevenBefore AND @SevenAfter
```

Now, you say that the CreatedDate is a column in a table. For this example, I will assume that the CreatedDate is in a table other than the one in your example above. For this purpose, I will give two fake names to the tables. The table with the CreatedDate, I will call `tblCreated`, and the one from the query above I will call tblData.

Looking above, it's pretty obvious that you can't compare an entire table row to a date. There must be a field in that table that contains a date/time value. I will call this column `TargetDate`.

Given these assumptions, your query would look something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblCreated tc
INNER JOIN tblData td
    ON td.TargetDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -7, tc.CreatedDate) and DATEADD(day, 7, tc.CreatedDate)
```

Looking at this, it is clear that you still need some other associations between the tables. Do you only want all data rows per customer based on the Created date, or perhaps only want Creations where some work was done on them as shown in the Data records, or ??. Without a fuller specification, we can't help with that, though.